# Get a function reference with decltype(this)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a macro that will install and remove a Qt event filter constructed from a lambda. In this case, `this` is known to be a `QObject`, and thus has a member `destroyed`. `filter` is just some `QObject`-derived event filter. However I have a problem with the line:

```
connect(this, &decltype(this)::destroyed, [filter]() 
{ 
    qApp->removeEventFilter(filter); 
    filter->deleteLater();
});
```

which gives the (MSVC2013) error:

> left of '::' must be a class, struct or union

Am I just getting the syntax wrong, or can I not do this?

Comment: `this` is a pointer.

Comment: Put a ``using`` statement (defining ``decltype(*this)`` as an alias) before and use the alias instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @molbdnilo's comment, I wasn't accounting for the fact that `this` is a pointer. Using a type-trait to remove the pointer made it work:

```
connect(this, &std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type::destroyed, [filter]() 
{
    qApp->removeEventFilter(filter);
    filter->deleteLater();
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that c++14 introduces `std::remove_pointer_t<T>` which replaces `typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks for pointing that out, I was stuck with msvc2013/c++11 for this particular task though!

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: Why not just use `&decltype(*this)::destroyed`? Or even just `&destroyed`, since you are clearly already inside a class that defines `destroyed()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The former is invalid for using `::` on a reference type; the latter doesn't form a pointer to member.

Comment: @T.C. I don't see how `std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type` is any different than `decltype(*this)>`, they both return the same type. If one can be used with `::` then they both should. As for `&destroyed`, it does work in some compilers. Maybe not in VS, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, they are not the same type. Why don't you try it?